# Javascript HighCharts Math Operations in ToolTip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to draw a chart based on values which I get from DB with no problem so far.

Now what I am trying to do is to display another information on the tooltip which uses a constant called **unitPrice** and multiplies that constant with point.y

```
tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true,
                headerFormat: '<small>{point.key}</small><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">{series.name}: </td>' + 
                    '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y} kWh</b></td><td style="text-align: right"><b>'+ (this.y * unitPrice) + '</b></td></tr>', // {series.unit}
                footerFormat: '</table>',

            },
```

multiplication is NaN as you can see below.

Here's what I meant:

[image]

It supposed to multiply 11829.68 with 0.41 (which is unitPrice value) instead I get **NaN**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `this.y`? Also `11,829.68` is not valid number, so...you get the point. For example `0,41` should be `0.41` and `11,829.68` should be `11.82968`. Then if you try to multiply them, you will get a correct result.

Comment: It should be y axis. In that specific point 11,829.68 as seen in the picture

Comment: @Ionut it's 11829.68 I format number to display like this

Comment: Please provide a working snippet that shows the problem you have.

Comment: @Ionut editted the formatting. What I'm trying is to get y axis value and multiply it with some another value and show it in tooltip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access `this` with current [`Point` object](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Point) you should use [`pointFormatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter) callback function (you can't access [`this` in `pointFormat`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.tooltip.pointFormat)).

See example below:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function() { 
          return this.series.name + ' : <b>' + this.y 
                + ' (some math here : ' + this.y * 2.5 + ')</b><br/>'; 
        },
        shared: true
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'dogs',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        name: 'cats',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4].reverse()
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake now. To be able to use "this.y" pointFormatter must be used